# AWS-CDK failing to create bucket notification with S3BucketNotifications PutBucketNotificationConfiguration operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

```
self.bucket = aws_s3.Bucket(
  scope,
  bucket_name,
  bucket_name=bucket_name,
)

self.bucket.add_to_resource_policy(
                iam_.PolicyStatement(
                    actions=["s3:GetBucket*", "s3:List*", "s3:GetObject"],
                    principals=[iam_.ArnPrincipal(cdk_config.role_arn_dayforce_lambda)],
                    resources=[self.bucket.bucket_arn, f"{self.bucket.bucket_arn}/*"],
                )
            )
self.sns_topic = aws_sns.Topic(
            self.scope,
            id=self.id,
            topic_name=self.name,
            display_name=self.name,
            fifo=False,
            **kwargs
        )

notification = s3_notify.SnsDestination(sns_topic)

self.bucket.add_event_notification(
                s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED, notification, s3.NotificationKeyFilter(suffix=".xml")
            )
```

Now with this I am getting below error and the Bucket SNS Event notification is failing.

```
CREATE_FAILED        | Custom::S3BucketNotifications   | dayforce-regional-dev/Notifications
Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: Error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutBucketNotificationCo
nfiguration operation: Access Denied. See the details in CloudWatch Log Stream: 2023/07/03/[$LATEST]ebe0fe1fcff54f3787f9b7d6ff1f0b3b (RequestId: 96600ba3-
ed8e-4596-aa35-d6c087099413)
```

I tried to add explicitly the `S3:PutBucketNotification` like below didn't help

```
self.bucket.add_to_resource_policy(
            iam_.PolicyStatement(
                actions=["s3:PutBucketNotification"],
                principals=[iam_.ServicePrincipal("s3.amazonaws.com")],
                resources=["*"],
            )
        )
```

Below are the `iam-policy-report` for the same stack got created part of `cdk synth`

```
{
    "roles": [
       {
            "roleConstructPath": "Dsp-StoreServiceStack-dev/BucketNotificationsHandler050a0587b7544547bf325f094a3db834/Role",
            "roleName": "missing role",
            "missing": true,
            "assumeRolePolicy": [
                {
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "managedPolicyArns": [
                "arn:(PARTITION):iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
            ],
            "managedPolicyStatements": [],
            "identityPolicyStatements": [
                {
                    "Action": "s3:PutBucketNotification",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Resource": "*"
                }
            ]
        }
     ]
}
```

Comment: Where are you running this code from? is it an EC2 instance? your personal machine? or Code Deploy? what level of IAM permissions does the entity running this CDK have?

Comment: I am running it from my local system only. The AWS credentials I am using got `AWSAdministratorAccess`.